# Eloquent model using multiple table query

Tags: laravel-5

I have two table
Email (id,content,folder_id)
Folder (id,name)

In model

```
public function folder() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Folder');
    }

 public function email() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Email');
    }
```

In Controller, I want list all email for each folder from a request

```
public function mailbox ($foldername) {
$data=Email::with('folder')->orderBy('id','DESC')->where('??????',$foldername)->get()->toArray();
        return view('dashboard.mailbox.mailbox',compact('data'));
    }
```

The problem is: how can i get name (with ???? in code below) from Folder table to where with input request ->

It's OK if i go with $id request, but I want a beautiful response, so please help me

Comment: You want beautiful response or data ?

Comment: Can you print the array that you got ?

Comment: Thanks. I did it OK with  `public function mailbox($foldername) {
  $datas = DB::table('mailbox_folders')->where('foldername',$foldername)
  ->leftJoin('mailboxes', 'mailbox_folders.id', '=', 'mailboxes.folder_id')->get();
  return view('dashboard.mailbox.mailbox',compact('datas'));
 }`

Comment: What is your json response ?